# Custom std::function-like implementation for both free and member functions

Tags: c++, templates, delegates, variadic-templates, std-function

I needed something like std::function but then I found [this](https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2011/09/19/generic-type-safe-delegates-and-events-in-c/) which is faster (as the author claims) and can even be compared by the == operator. I adapted it to allow a dynamic return type and arguments, like this:

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class Delegate {};

template<typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class Delegate<TReturn(TArgs...)> final
{
private:
    typedef void* InstancePointer;
    typedef TReturn (*InternalFunction)(InstancePointer, TArgs...);

private:
    // Turns a free function into our internal function stub
    template <TReturn (*FreeFunction)(TArgs...)>
    static TReturn FreeFunctionStub(InstancePointer instance, TArgs... args) {
        // We don't need the instance pointer because we're dealing with free functions
        return (FreeFunction)(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }

    // Turns a member function into our internal function stub
    template <class TClass, TReturn (TClass::*MemberFunction)(TArgs...)>
    static TReturn MemberFunctionStub(InstancePointer instance, TArgs... args) {
        // Cast the instance pointer back into the original class instance
        return (static_cast<TClass*>(instance)->*MemberFunction)(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }

public:
    Delegate() = default;

    // Resets this delegate to a new free function
    template <TReturn(*FreeFunction)(TArgs...)>
    void reset() {
        m_instance = nullptr;
        m_function = &FreeFunctionStub<FreeFunction>;
    }

    // Resets this delegate to a new member function
    template <class TClass, TReturn(TClass::*MemberFunction)(TArgs...)>
    void reset(TClass* instance) {
        m_instance = instance;
        m_function = &MemberFunctionStub<TClass, MemberFunction>;
    }

    // Resets this delegate to a new free function
    void specialReset(TReturn(*FreeFunction)(TArgs...)) {
        m_instance = nullptr;
        m_function = ???
    }

    // Resets this delegate to a new member function
    template<class TClass>
    void specialReset(TClass *instance, TReturn(TClass::*MemberFunction)(TArgs...)) {
        m_instance = instance;
        m_function = ???
    }

    // Invokes this delegate
    TReturn invoke(TArgs... args) const {
        if (m_function == nullptr)
            throw new std::runtime_error(""Unbound delegate! Call reset() first."");

        return m_function(m_instance, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }

private:
    InstancePointer m_instance;
    InternalFunction m_function;
};
```

The usage goes like that:

```
Delegate<void()> del1;
Delegate<int(double)> del2;

del1.reset<&someParameterlessVoidFreeFunction>();
del1.invoke();

del2.reset<SomeClass, &SomeClass::someIntMemberFunction>(&someClassInstance);
del2.invoke(24.2);
```

What I am trying to do is to achieve something like this (IMO, much cleaner and intuitive):

```
Delegate<void()> del1;
Delegate<int(double)> del2;

del1.reset(&someParameterlessVoidFreeFunction);
del1.invoke();

del2.reset(&SomeClass::someIntMemberFunction, &someClassInstance);
del2.invoke(24.2);
```

However, I dont quite understand the `m_function` concept. What I am trying to achive is even possible? How could I do that?

Also, what exactly is the `<TReturn(TArgs...)>` part of class Delegate and why do we need to define a `class Delegate {};` first?

Comment: Is this for an academic reason or a practical one? For a practical one, you'll probably save a lot of headaches by using `std::function` anyway even if it's allegedly slower. You don't appear to be needing the `operator==` functionality here.

Comment: operator== is used somewhere that doesnt matter. I'm aware of std::function (this has been stated at the very beginning) and I don't want to/can't use it.

Comment: Well, I'll mention that your syntax `del2.reset(&SomeClass::someIntMemberFunction, &someClassInstance);` is unlikely to work without some really hacky code that sets static data. This is because the difference between passing a function pointer as a template argument versus as a parameter argument is that the template argument's value is known at compile-time (function pointer is integer type) and the parameter argument isn't known until run-time.

Comment: Exactly. What I'm looking for is that "hacky code" :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so after days of researchs, developing and testing, I made up something that does accomplish a faster `std::function/std::bind` with a much better syntax.

For those wondering, take a look at [Delegator](https://github.com/YvesHenri/Delegator). I can't paste the whole code here because it got too big to be posted here. Also, at this link you'll always have the lastest version.

With Delegator, you can do the following:

```
Delegate<void(void)> d1; // Blank delegate
Delegate<void(void)> d2(&freeFunction); // Delegate to a free function
Delegate<void(void)> d3(&SomeClass::someClassStaticFunction); // Delegate to a static function
Delegate<void(void)> d4(&SomeClass::someClassFunction, &someClassInstance); // Delegate to a member function
Delegate<void(void)> d5(&SomeClass::someClassConstFunction, &someClassInstance); // Delegate to a member const function

d1.reset(); // Resets the delegate
d1.reset(&freeFunction); // Resets the delegate to a free function
d1.reset(&SomeClass::someClassStaticFunction); // Resets the delegate to a static function
d1.reset(&SomeClass::someClassFunction, &someClassInstance); // Resets the delegate to a member function
d1.reset(&SomeClass::someClassConstFunction, &someClassInstance); // Resets the delegate to a member const function
d1.reset(&d2); // Resets the delegate to d2's state
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the solution for your syntax is to get closer to what we'd do to implement `std::function` and sacrifice speed for flexibility (due to use of run-time polymorphism instead of pure templating)

The first call can be solved by adding another member variable to your `Delegate` class to hold free functions:

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class Delegate<TReturn(TArgs...)> final
{
    // ...
    typedef TReturn(*FreeFunctionType)(TArgs...);
    FreeFunctionType m_free_function = nullptr;
};
```

Now you can set `m_free_function` within `specialReset`, while resetting the other members:

```
void specialReset(TReturn(*FreeFunction)(TArgs...)) {
    m_instance = nullptr;
    m_function = nullptr;
    m_free_function = FreeFunction;
}
```

And calling it performs an additional null check:

```
TReturn invoke(TArgs... args) const {
    if (m_function == nullptr && m_free_function == nullptr)
        throw new std::runtime_error("Unbound delegate! Call reset() first.");
    else if (m_function)
        return m_function(m_instance, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    else return m_free_function(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
}
```

and a test:

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Called foo()\n";
}

int main()
{
    Delegate<void()> del1;

    del1.specialReset(&::foo);
    del1.invoke();
}
```

The second one is a little trickier.

The idea for solving this is to declare an abstract base class pointer that we can derive from later for making our call:

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class Delegate<TReturn(TArgs...)> final
{
private:
    //...
    struct ICall
    {
        virtual TReturn doCall(TArgs... args) = 0;
    };
     std::unique_ptr<ICall> caller;
};
```

Usually this pointer will be `nullptr`, which we can check for, but otherwise we can call the function in `invoke`:

```
// Invokes this delegate
TReturn invoke(TArgs... args) const {
    if (m_function == nullptr && m_free_function == nullptr && caller == nullptr)
        throw new std::runtime_error("Unbound delegate! Call reset() first.");
    else if (m_function)
        return m_function(m_instance, std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    else if (caller)
        return caller->doCall(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    else 
        return m_free_function(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
}
```

And finally the implementation of our second `specialReset` where we create a derived class and set our pointer:

```
template<class TClass>
void specialReset(TClass *instance, TReturn(TClass::*MemberFunc)(TArgs...)) {
    m_instance = nullptr;
    m_function = nullptr;
    m_free_function = nullptr;
    struct DerivedCall : public ICall
    {
        DerivedCall(TClass* _instance, TReturn(TClass::*_func)(TArgs...)) : m_instance(_instance), m_func(_func){}
        TReturn doCall(TArgs... args) override
        {
            return (m_instance->*m_func)(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
        }
        TClass* m_instance;
        TReturn(TClass::*m_func)(TArgs...);
    };
    caller = std::make_unique<DerivedCall>(instance, MemberFunc);
}
```

And a test:

```
struct A{
    int foo(double){std::cout << "Called A::foo\n"; return 42;}
};

int main()
{ 
    Delegate<int(double)> del2;
    A a;

    del2.specialReset(&a, &A::foo);
    del2.invoke(24.2);
}
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Aipf97g0lVgKMvtL)

I'm sure someone more clever than I can come up with something better. As I said. We're probably already losing the precious speed that you advocated for over `std::function` because of the runtimeyness of this all, and I'm not sure what it does for the `operator==` (It probably became infeasible the second I created `m_free_function`). We cannot use `specialReset` with lambdas here (...yet).

Comment: Thanks for your time! After searching for hours, I finally found this: http://pastebin.com/tkuAgzSc
Unfortunately, even thought the usage is EXACTLY what I wanted, it does not help me because you need to specify the function pointer type (either (*) for free functions or (SomeClass::*) for member functions) as the template argument. This is bad because a class will store these delegates as some of their members and it doesnt know which kind of delegate it'll be (It's an event system I'm working on). Also, I've read about the C++11 `decltype`, but still, no success. Any ideas?

Comment: @YvesHenri: You neglected to mention how my answer doesn't help you. The reason all those other approaches accept the function pointer as a template argument is because those are known at compile time and can be wrapped nicely. If you want your syntax, you'll have to settle for run-time type erasure, which is slower.

Comment: It doesnt help me becuase, as you even said, we're losing the speed and the == operator, not to mention the confusing code for the `specialReset(member_function)`. The link I posted on my reply BEAUTIFULY does what I asked (it even is fast and is comparable), but then we lose the flexibility of declaring a Delegate object that should work with both free and member functions (multiple reset calls for different functions). What I want is somewhat the middle of the two.