# How can I pass a function as argument regardless of its return type in C++ ? (without using a template parameter for the passed function)

Tags: c++, function, templates, std-function

I'm trying to make a map function. *(recap: a map function is a function which applies a function to each items in a collection)*.

That sounds cool, but I want my map function to get as argument a function with **any return type**. However, I don't want to use native code snippets such as **std::function**.
**With std::function**
Note that even with *void* return type, it works with any input function regardless of its return type (the result I'm looking for)

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void map(function<void(T&)> f, T * collection, unsigned length)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++)
        f(collection[i]);
}
```

**An approach that doesn't work for non-void return type functions**

```
template <typename T>
void map(void (*f)(T&), T * collection, unsigned length)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++)
        f(collection[i]);
}
```

**My solution**

```
template <typename T, typename any>
void map(any (*f)(T&), T * collection, unsigned length)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++)
        f(collection[i]);
}
```

Have you a solution that doesn't use a second template parameter ?
How should map be used regardless of its implementation (example):

```
#include "map.h"
#include <iostream>

void square(int& i){ i *= i; }

int main()
{
    int integers[] = { 5, 3, 2, 9 };

    map(&square, integers, 4);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << integers[i] << std::endl;
    
    /*Output:
    25
     9
     4
    81
    */
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. What's the issue exactly with your solution that takes 2 template parameters?

Comment: *"But I don't think that's the best way to do it."* -- why not? Which aspect of your solution do you find lacking?

Comment: What do you do you want to do with the return value?

Comment: @cigien I'm asking if there is a solution with only 1 template parameter(T) because in my solution: "any" is an ugly way to put the right function return type. Unfortunaly, **void (*f)(T&)** doesn't work :/

Comment: If you want a solution with only one template parameter, then you should specify that in the question. (You probably won't like the solution, but that's a different issue). The question has been closed as a dupe, but it's incorrect (unless I'm mistaken, you're not looking for an STL function that does what you want, but are trying to improve the function you've written yourself). If you edit the question to state *precisely* what the issue is, and what your criteria for improvement are, I'll go ahead and reopen it.

Comment: @KenY-N I'm searching a solution without using any std classes / functions / macros :)

Comment: So if std::function does what you want with only one template parameter and you don't want to use stuff from the standard, just implement your own version of std::function yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453145/how-is-stdfunction-implemented  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739902/is-there-a-standalone-implementation-of-stdfunction  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705830/custom-stdfunction-like-implementation-for-both-free-and-member-functions

Comment: I don't think you can do without an extra template parameter or something equivalent to that.  The platform may have calling conventions that require different code to call functions with different return types.  So the compiler has to know the return type of `f` at compile time, and has to instantiate a separate function for every return type.

Comment: Btw, don't be tempted to use your `void (*f)(T&)` approach and something like `other_type f(int); map(reinterpret_cast<void (*)(int)>(f), ...)`.  On many platforms you may get away with it if `other_type` is something simple like `int` or pointer (where the return value goes in a register that can just be ignored), but it will likely blow up as soon as `other_type` is a class or struct (which are often returned by having the caller pass a hidden extra argument to an address where the return value will be stored).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void m(auto f, auto c)
{
   for(auto i : c)
      f(i);
}
 
int main() {
    m(
        [](int x) { cout << x << '\n'; },
        vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}
```

Do you consider `auto` a template?  You can make `c` (and `i`) mutable by taking them by reference.